# Why I can't get the value of a select option html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

So I have listed a number of categories, each of these categories has a value of appropriate id, the idea is after the category is being changed to send ajax request to the server, but before that I have to get the id of the category I selected, the problem is that after each time I try to get the value I get this error message

```
app.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at C.fn.init.val (app.js:1)
at sortByCategory (news:174)
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (news:215)
```

The problem is that it returns me the whole window object and I don't know how to get just the value of the selected option.

html -

```
<select onchange="sortByCategory()" name="category">
                            @foreach($categories as $category)
                                <option value="{!! $category->id !!}">
                                    {{ $category->title }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

javascript -

```
 function sortByCategory(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/home/sortByCategory',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data : {
            category : 'bar'
        },
        success:function(data){
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post all relevant code currently there is nothing related to toLowerCase

Comment: Please, create fiddle so others can help you faster.

Comment: After I changed onchnage to id and put this snippet absolutely nothing happens$('#sortByCategory').on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value);
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an event handler (like "onchange") send *this* as an argument, like this:

```js
function sortByCategory(el){
  alert($(el).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="sortByCategory(this)" name="category">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

A better solution would be to separate the JavaScript code from the HTML code like this:

```js
$("#category").on("change", function() {
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="category" id="category">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you want to get a value from a select you can to read its value from the html. In your case it would be something like: https://jsfiddle.net/jm4kLe65/11/

You need to pass the select object (`this`) to your `sortByCategory()` function, and from there you can access many of its properties. In your case you are only interested in its selected value which you can access by `select.value`